# cant run anaconda although the path variable is set

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

i have installed anaconda but when i try to run it by writing python,terminal loads the default python
this is my PATH variable :

```
 /home/karen/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

and how can i switch between them?

i use ubuntu15.10

Comment: what is the output of `which -a python`? and `ls /home/karen/anaconda2/bin`?

Comment: /usr/bin/python is for which -a python